# USB3 drive and Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-zero, hard-drive, usb3

I'm trying to connect a 3.5" drive to a Pi Zero. However, the drive is not detected by the Pi:

```
pi@lolcat:~ $ dmesg | grep sd
[    0.913523] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.915989] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.922065] sdhost-bcm2835 20202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.924933] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.045473] sdhost: log_buf @ db513000 (5b513000)
[    2.135895] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[   10.863656] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin for chip 0x00a9a6(43430) rev 0x000001
pi@lolcat:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
pi@lolcat:~ $
```

I am using a simple OTG adapter which has worked fine with USB sticks. The drive is connected and powered via a standalone SATA to USB3 adapter (i.e. no hub involved). A photo of the setup follows.

[image: Pi Zero]

Any suggestions on what could be wrong with this setup?

---

dmesg output:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.14.98+ (dom@dom-XPS-13-9370) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611)) #1200 Tue Feb 12 20:11:02 GMT 2019
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7), cr=00c5387d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT nonaliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] OF: fdt: Machine model: Raspberry Pi Zero W Rev 1.1
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writeback
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x1b400000
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 114688
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat c09caaf0, node_mem_map db010000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 1008 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 114688 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s0 r0 d32768 u32768 alloc=1*32768
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 113680
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=656 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=416 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:AD:EC:4A vc_mem.mem_base=0x1ec00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x20000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=9596604c-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 32768 (order: 5, 131072 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 435208K/458752K available (6451K kernel code, 589K rwdata, 1992K rodata, 440K init, 673K bss, 15352K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
                   vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
                   fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
                   vmalloc : 0xdc800000 - 0xff800000   ( 560 MB)
                   lowmem  : 0xc0000000 - 0xdc000000   ( 448 MB)
                   modules : 0xbf000000 - 0xc0000000   (  16 MB)
                     .text : 0xc0008000 - 0xc0655050   (6453 kB)
                     .init : 0xc08d4000 - 0xc0942000   ( 440 kB)
                     .data : 0xc0942000 - 0xc09d54f8   ( 590 kB)
                      .bss : 0xc09dadf0 - 0xc0a8338c   ( 674 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=32, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=1, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 24128 entries in 71 pages
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 16, nr_irqs: 16, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000029] sched_clock: 32 bits at 1000kHz, resolution 1000ns, wraps every 2147483647500ns
[    0.000073] clocksource: timer: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 1911260446275 ns
[    0.000166] bcm2835: system timer (irq = 27)
[    0.000743] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001344] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001405] Calibrating delay loop... 697.95 BogoMIPS (lpj=3489792)
[    0.060342] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.060860] Mount-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.060916] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.062253] Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.062474] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.063661] Setting up static identity map for 0x8200 - 0x8238
[    0.064966] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.074456] random: get_random_u32 called from bucket_table_alloc+0x88/0x1c4 with crng_init=0
[    0.075377] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 1 part 20 variant b rev 5
[    0.075810] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.075884] futex hash table entries: 256 (order: -1, 3072 bytes)
[    0.077238] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.078657] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.081634] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.088169] hw-breakpoint: found 6 breakpoint and 1 watchpoint registers.
[    0.088242] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 4 bytes.
[    0.088388] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.091360] bcm2835-mbox 2000b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.092158] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.132270] bcm2835-dma 20007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at dc80d000, dmachans=0x1
[    0.134613] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.134894] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.135034] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.135270] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.140817] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2019-03-27 15:45
[    0.142866] clocksource: Switched to clocksource timer
[    0.228726] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.228906] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.229229] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.229588] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.246783] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.248010] TCP established hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.248143] TCP bind hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.248262] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 4096 bind 4096)
[    0.248441] UDP hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.248499] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 256 (order: 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.248871] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.249628] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.249685] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.249713] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.249738] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.251653] hw perfevents: no irqs for PMU, sampling events not supported
[    0.251784] hw perfevents: enabled with armv6_1176 PMU driver, 3 counters available
[    0.255649] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=17 bucket_order=3
[    0.267959] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.269358] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.269450] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.269483] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.269531] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    0.274394] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
[    0.274879] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.274929] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.275486] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.275533] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    0.275563] io scheduler kyber registered
[    0.277884] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory 5b500000
[    0.277999] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ dc80d000
[    0.286134] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 82x26
[    0.295003] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
[    0.300502] bcm2835-rng 20104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    0.303675] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x1ec00000 mem_size:0x20000000(512 MiB)
[    0.309956] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    0.313463] gpiomem-bcm2835 20200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0x20200000
[    0.337424] brd: module loaded
[    0.352136] loop: module loaded
[    0.355006] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    0.358477] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    0.361174] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    0.392002] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: base=0xf0980000
[    0.594985] Core Release: 2.80a
[    0.597607] Setting default values for core params
[    0.600240] Finished setting default values for core params
[    0.803308] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    0.806069] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.808779] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    0.811579] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    0.814473] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    0.818098] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1046: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xdb514000 dma = 0x5b514000 len=9024
[    0.823759] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
               Non-periodic Split Transactions
               Periodic Split Transactions
               High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
               Interrupt/Control Split Transaction hack enabled
[    0.836489] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    0.836739] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:459: FIQ on core 0 at 0xc04a00d0
[    0.839407] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:460: FIQ ASM at 0xc04a03ac length 36
[    0.841971] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:486: MPHI regs_base at 0xf0006000
[    0.844681] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.847388] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    0.850089] dwc_otg 20980000.usb: irq 56, io mem 0x00000000
[    0.852720] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    0.855341] Init: Power Port (0)
[    0.858191] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    0.860794] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.863451] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    0.866007] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.14.98+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    0.868555] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 20980000.usb
[    0.872172] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.874856] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    0.878175] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    0.878187] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    0.878194] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    0.878213] Module dwc_common_port init
[    0.878722] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    0.881677] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    0.884297] IR NEC protocol handler initialized
[    0.886770] IR RC5(x/sz) protocol handler initialized
[    0.889239] IR RC6 protocol handler initialized
[    0.891629] IR JVC protocol handler initialized
[    0.893995] IR Sony protocol handler initialized
[    0.896364] IR SANYO protocol handler initialized
[    0.898711] IR Sharp protocol handler initialized
[    0.900951] IR MCE Keyboard/mouse protocol handler initialized
[    0.903368] IR XMP protocol handler initialized
[    0.906969] bcm2835-wdt 20100000.watchdog: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    0.909912] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=700000 max=1000000
[    0.913097] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    0.915566] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    0.918553] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.921704] sdhost-bcm2835 20202000.mmc: could not get clk, deferring probe
[    0.924543] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    0.927625] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    0.930361] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    0.933356] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    0.936001] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    0.939495] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = db580000, is_master = 0
[    0.944248] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    0.954528] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    0.958288] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    0.961066] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    0.963998] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    0.968378] registered taskstats version 1
[    0.979163] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    0.982242] 20201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x20201000 (irq = 81, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    0.990532] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.993501] 20215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 160, base_baud = 31250000) is a 16550
[    1.958783] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.966824] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.975760] mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    2.045397] sdhost: log_buf @ db513000 (5b513000)
[    2.085686] random: fast init done
[    2.094664] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.104772] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.114785] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.125878] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.133943] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.143261] of_cfs_init
[    2.148276] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.175055] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=9596604c-02...
[    2.284864] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.302674] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.322045] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.330973] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB
[    2.344009]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.388533] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.401716] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    2.423305] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.431349] Freeing unused kernel memory: 440K
[    2.438482] This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
[    2.944299] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    3.087724] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[    3.096981] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    3.119433] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[    3.154261] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.175695] systemd[1]: systemd 232 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN)
[    3.204578] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    3.231303] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <lolcat>.
[    3.304300] random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    3.554848] random: systemd-sysv-ge: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
[    4.288390] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    4.303030] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    4.315878] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    4.328752] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    4.343576] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    4.361892] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    4.386341] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    4.742078] i2c /dev entries driver
[    6.944158] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[    7.425086] systemd-journald[76]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   10.277049] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   10.353166] bcm2835_alsa bcm2835_alsa: card created with 8 channels
[   11.632485] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
[   11.658902] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin for chip 0x00a9a6(43430) rev 0x000001
[   11.659301] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[   12.271274] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 23 2017 03:55:53 version 7.45.98.38 (r674442 CY) FWID 01-e58d219f
[   12.274369] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 7.11.15 Compiler: 1.24.2 ClmImport: 1.24.1 Creation: 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc Data: 9.10.39 Inc Compiler: 1.29.4 Inc ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation: 2017-10-23 03:47:14 
[   14.439925] random: crng init done
[   14.439951] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[   14.735282] uart-pl011 20201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[   16.785262] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   19.400602] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.400722] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   19.400732] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.400761] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.400777] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.400862] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.435957] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   19.435976] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   19.435981] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   19.437449] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   20.222960] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   20.222976] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   20.223010] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.789998] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[   20.790020] brcmfmac: power management disabled
[   22.003420] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
```

Comment: Could you post a *complete* (non-grepped) `dmesg` log around the moment you plug in the drive? Or is it plugged all the time? In which case, plug it into a running system and collect the log.

Comment: I've tried both. No response in either case for the disk. With the USB stick there were some errors displayed when plugging it in with the pi powered on, and it worked fine if I had it plugged at boot time. I'll add a full dmesg later today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit turned out to be the mini OTG adapter: It is cute, but it doesn't work with the hard drive. Switching to a regular OTG cable made the drive appear.

Following is a diff of the boot messages when using the mini OTG adapter and the OTG cable. The message timestamps have been removed to produce a clean diff. Someone more familiar with Pi hardware can perhaps explain what went wrong from this.

```
--- connected-miniotg.p.txt 2019-06-12 21:43:36.767350223 +0200
+++ connected-cableotg.p.txt    2019-06-12 21:43:24.967383295 +0200
@@ -178,24 +178,32 @@
 mmc-bcm2835 20300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
 sdhost: log_buf @ db513000 (5b513000)
 random: fast init done
+Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
 mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
 mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
-mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
-mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
 mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
 of_cfs_init
 of_cfs_init: OK
+mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
 Waiting for root device PARTUUID=9596604c-02...
-mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
+mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
+usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
+Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
 mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
 mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address aaaa
 mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SC16G 14.8 GiB
  mmcblk0: p1 p2
+mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
 EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
 VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
 devtmpfs: mounted
 Freeing unused kernel memory: 440K
 This architecture does not have kernel memory protection.
+usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1f75, idProduct=0611
+usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=5, SerialNumber=6
+usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 20150327
+usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
+scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
 systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
 NET: Registered protocol family 10
 Segment Routing with IPv6
@@ -205,26 +213,37 @@
 systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
 systemd[1]: Set hostname to <lolcat>.
 random: systemd: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
+scsi host0: scsi scan: INQUIRY result too short (5), using 36
+scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ST315005 41AS                  PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
 random: systemd-sysv-ge: uninitialized urandom read (16 bytes read)
-systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
-systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
+ sda: sda1 sda2
+sd 0:0:0:0: 
 systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
+systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
 systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
+systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
 systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
 systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
-systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
+systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
+random: crng init done
+random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
 i2c /dev entries driver
 EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
-systemd-journald[76]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
+systemd-journald[66]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
 snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
 bcm2835_alsa bcm2835_alsa: card created with 8 channels
 brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x1541a9a6
 brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_map_chip_to_name: using brcm/brcmfmac43430-sdio.bin for chip 0x00a9a6(43430) rev 0x000001
 usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
+usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
 brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware version = wl0: Oct 23 2017 03:55:53 version 7.45.98.38 (r674442 CY) FWID 01-e58d219f
 brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: CLM version = API: 12.2 Data: 7.11.15 Compiler: 1.24.2 ClmImport: 1.24.1 Creation: 2014-05-26 10:53:55 Inc Data: 9.10.39 Inc Compiler: 1.29.4 Inc ClmImport: 1.36.3 Creation: 2017-10-23 03:47:14 
-random: crng init done
-random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
+sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
 uart-pl011 20201000.serial: no DMA platform data
 Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
 Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the answer to your own question that you discovered!